# Disabling Window Resize buttons using SetWindowPos not working with Edge Browser

Tags: windows, winapi

We have a constrain that requires us to, among others, remove (or disable) the resize and minimize buttons from Edge Brower which will be run in fullscreen mode (So not using Kiosk mode).

Looking online there are many examples of using the native user32 API method SetWinPos. This is fine for most apps but somehow it does not work with Windows Edge Browser. It just keeps displaying the buttons although the methods returns success.

Here is the example code:

```
Param([String]$procName,[String]$WndTitle = ".")


$iCount = 0

$GWL_STYLE        = -16

$WS_MAXIMIZEBOX   = 0x00010000
$WS_MINIMIZEBOX   = 0x00020000

$SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020
$SWP_NOMOVE       = 0x0002
$SWP_NOSIZE       = 0x0001



Function DisableWindowResize ([string]$name, [string]$title)
   {
   Add-Type -M '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd,int nIndex);
                [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd,int nIndex,IntPtr dwNewLong);
                [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,int X,int Y,int cx,int cy,uint uFlags);' -Name ps -Names w;


   ####  Get the handle of the specified window.

   $hWnd = (Get-Process $name -errorvariable MyErr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Where({$_.MainWindowTitle -Match $title},1).MainWindowHandle


   ####  Wait for the process for up to a second

   While ($MyErr -or (-not($hwnd))) {
      If ($iCount++ -eq 10) {Break}
      Start-Sleep -m 100
      $hWnd = (Get-Process $name -errorvariable MyErr -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Where({$_.MainWindowTitle -Match $title},1).MainWindowHandle
      }
      
   ####  Remove the Minimize and Resize buttons

   If ((-Not ($MyErr)) -and ($Hwnd)) {
      $iOldStyle = [w.ps]::GetWindowLong($hWnd, $GWL_STYLE)
      $iNewStyle = ($iOldStyle -bxor $WS_MINIMIZEBOX -bxor $WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)


      If ($iOldStyle -eq [w.ps]::SetWindowLong($hWnd, $GWL_STYLE, $iNewStyle)) {

          $Success = [w.ps]::SetWindowPos($hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ($SWP_FRAMECHANGED -bor $SWP_NOMOVE -bor $SWP_NOSIZE))
          }
      }
   }
```

Does anyone have experience with this or perhaps have another solution to meet the requirements.

Thanx,
Martijn

Comment: If you need that sort of control, why not host a [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) in a window of your own creation?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `WS_SIZEBOX` also?

Comment: Thank @IInspectable. I've been playing with the WebView2 control this weekend and looks like it can do what we require. Only think is that i need to discuss some requirements with our customer regarding software dependencies and required packages.

Comment: @IInspectable is it me or does the WebVew2 does not work with the preinstalled edge version but only one of the separate runtime options?

Comment: To my knowledge, the WebView2 control is deployed as an individual [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2), that contains all pre-built binaries. I am not aware of a way to use the Edge browser installed with the OS. You would need to include the NuGet package with your deployment package.